# Group By Grouping Sets Returning Unexpected Result

Tags: t-sql

I have a table on which I'm using Group by Group Sets and it is returning one row of data that I do not understand. I was hope you all could help me make sense of it:

[image]

The first row that is returned contains Null for both Balance and WarehouseNo, but I know that the Total Value corresponds to WarehouseNo WW-COI with Balance as Null (see second image proving this).

[image]

Why does it appear as null when using Group By Grouping Sets?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a couple different confusions going on here.

`Grouping sets` are usually used for getting rid of `Union All` where you need different groupings on the *same* table.

In your case, you are keeping your `Union All` because it is on two different tables.

So, from what it seems, you probably just want to use a normal `Group By` to keep your groupings linked together.  It's not clear to me why you'd need `grouping sets` here.

Now... to answer your question:
Since you are using `grouping sets` on this unioned dataset, it is going to do a different grouping for the two sets you provided.

Concurrently, it is going to do a grouping on just `WarehouseNo` and separately at the same time it is going to do a different grouping of just `Balance`.

Not seeing your original data, this is probably the reason you are getting Nulls in places you didn't expect.

If you want the two columns to be linked, you would need to include them both in the same set. as in:

```
Group By Grouping Sets ((WarehouseNo, Balance), (another grouping you may want))
```

The "other grouping" could well be just (WarehouseNo) or (Balance) or even no grouping ().  But only you can decide why that information might be important to you.

So, from the looks of it, you probably just want to use a normal `Group By` here.  But quite possibly I'm missing something that I don't understand about your data and what you are trying to achieve with it.

Hope that helps. :)